# Share variables between functions in Swift

Tags: macos, cocoa, variables, swift, share

I started Swift today.
I have no idea how to share variables between functions. Does anyone have an idea?

```
@IBAction func function1(sender : NSButton) {
    var variable1 = 1
}
@IBAction func function2(sender: NSButton) {
    println(variable1)
}
```

I googled about this, but I couldn't find the solution.
I'm using Xcode6 beta6.

----EDITED----

The specific thing I wanted to do was the code below.

```
var files: [AnyObject] = [AnyObject]()
@IBAction func selectFiles(sender : NSButton) {
    let openDlg = NSOpenPanel()
    openDlg.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    openDlg.canChooseFiles = true
    openDlg.canChooseDirectories = true
    if openDlg.runModal() == NSOKButton{
        var files = openDlg.URLs
    }
}
@IBAction func startScript(sender: NSButton) {
    for var i = 0; i < files.count; i++ {
        var fileName:AnyObject = files[i];
        println(files[i])
    }
}
```

In fact, I wanted to open a dialog to select files, and log the paths of those files.
No error occurs in this code, but nothing is printed. How can I do so?

Comment: Don't you think you need a "global" variable for what you want to achieve.

Comment: See the edit in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you not declaring `variable1` outside and then use it in both of your functions as shown below:

```
var variable1 = 0 

@IBAction func function1(sender : NSButton) {
    variable1 = 1
}
@IBAction func function2(sender: NSButton) {
    println(variable1)
}
```

EDIT:
Based on the new code you posted, you are doing

```
var files = openDlg.URLs
```

Here, you are declaring a local variable and not using your global one. 
Remove the `var` from here and keep only

```
files = openDlg.URLs
```

Comment: Thanks! I could solve the problem and I succeeded in logging the paths.